# Firefox is not opening by using WebDriver at my workplace Cannot find firefox binary in PATH

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Hi I am trying to open Firefox to run the Webdriver java script.

```
public static WebDriver dr =null;
public static EventFiringWebDriver driver=null;

dr = new FirefoxDriver();

driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(dr);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If I run this code I am getting error like
**Can not fine firefox binary PATH**

At present I have written code like this to open Firefox.It is working fine in my own laptop.
If once I try to run this code in company laptop .

It is not working because fire fox has installed by my Tech support team.

If I right click on Firefox icon properties->

Target is showing like this

```
C:\Windows\System32\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe /launch "Firefox 15.0.1 15.0.1.4631"
```

So how can I open Firefox from my java script.

Can you please help me

If you need any more info please let me know.

**ERROR:**
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: VISTA
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Thanks

Comment: First update Selenium, it's at v2.28 now. Secondly, open Firefox, and then download Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), it will tell you the exact location of Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is way how to initialize FirefoxDriver:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile);
```

To do it more specifically, you can do it like this:

```
File ffpath = new File("path/to/firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffbinary = new FirefoxBinary(ffpath);
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffbinary,ffprofile);
```

The magic happens by the File ffpath, which has to show to firefox.exe binary properly. Ask your tech support where the binary is stored on your computer. I have bad feeling about your setup now: Seems like that your work PC does not have installed Firefox locally...

Comment: Now I have installed Firefox on my local machine.. So I am able to open firefox ... But it is stopping by Proxy... Can you please help me how to set proxy as Auto-detect proxy settings for this network by using script

Comment: It should heal itself by running the firefox manually and setting it up. After you set it up, it should work

Comment: @Raju, "proxy" is a separate question. This particular question has been answered, so accept the answer and ask next question. (or try researching first, e.g.: google it first)

Answer (score 1):

When you get the FF path, you can specify a `FirexoxBinary(new File("/path/to/FF"))` to pass to the `FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile)`

See [the docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by setting the Path of firefox.exe to the PATH Variable

If the firefox directory is `C:\Users\Tester\Applicaion\Firefox`,

Append this to the `ENVIRONMENT` variable `PATH`

And rerun the test

Comment: I installed Firfox in my local machine then it worked fine .. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Raju  Do you think that this answer has helped you ?

Answer (score -2):

1. Try Setting Up Firefox in External Browsers list by following below steps.
   `Eclipse > Window > General > Web Browser`
2. On Right side u can see the Web Browser with internal and External browsers options. Select `Use External web browser` and click on `New`.
3. Please give the Name as `Firefox` and add the location which is exactly where the firefox browser saved in your local machine (eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe).
4. Click on `OK`. Firefox option should display under External web browsers list.
5. Select the Firefox browser option by selcting the tick box and Apply the changes.

Hope this will work the firefox browser