# IntelliJ unable to find files

Tags: java, linux, selenium

I'm having a lot of problems with my Java Code unable to find files in System. When I wanted to read some textfiles in /etc/workingdir I got a "No such File or Directory" Error, but in fact those files did exist. Built a workaround by moving files to my homedir.

Now I am having same issues with Selenium Webdriver.
It's not finding the webdriver.

When I specify the path

```
  File pathToBinary = new File("/usr/bin/firefox");
```

I get error

> Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox

Installed System: Linux Mint 20.1

JDK: openjdk 16.0.1

I assume a permission issue ? But I'm too noobish to resolve, allthough I already tried some chmod lines, but seems like it didnt work out

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there no file ending to firefox? firefox.

Comment: Also, here's some possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233744/firefox-is-not-opening-by-using-webdriver-at-my-workplace-cannot-find-firefox-bi

Comment: File exists. I tried to specify the file like it has been wirtten in the link you mentioned, thats when I get the error. Same problem I have with geckodriver. Must be an overall permission issue (?)

Comment: no I wouldn't think it's a permission issue. You'd get a permission issue error then?

Comment: Are you telling me you tried this? : File ffpath = new File("path/to/firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffbinary = new FirefoxBinary(ffpath);
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffbinary,ffprofile);

Comment: Also notice how the path that I copied and they mention in that thread is always .exe and some guy even had the issue that he hadn't even downloaded firefox when he was trying to find its path.

Comment: try to launch Intellij with admin access and see if that works ?

Comment: Yes i tried that and it fails in not finding path. Another example: Icreate a txt file by "sudo nano /etc/test.txt" . I am able to write text in this file and save it. When I try to access this File in Java i get error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/test.txt (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1):

Installation of IntelliJ via Linux Mint Software Center was the reason.
It's a flatpack installation.
After uninstall and run IntelliJ from the official download with ./idea.sh & i can access to all files. Thanks for help

Comment: Great that you managed to solve it. Guess you were right about access then